# Blur the background of a <li> but not the content

Tags: html, html-lists, blur

I have a problem with my HTML template. I have to blur the background of this "li" and not the enteire content (the h1 got blurred if I put the blur option in the style section).
Have you got any idea?

```
<li style="background-image: url('test.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
<h1>Title</h1></li>
```

Thanks.

Comment: It may be just me, but IMO <h1> is not supposed to be used inside an <li>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what the question means, the second example blur both image and css:
http://jsfiddle.net/ignaciocorreia/Wn9F9/

The solution is to put them separately you cannot blub BG Images:

```
<li><div>image here</div><span>text here</span></li>
```

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ignaciocorreia/YLsQP/1/

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not getting exactly what u r saying by ->>> I have to blur the background of this "li" and not the enteire content <<<<

But you can do one thing..open your image in adobe photoshop (i.e. your test.png image) and reduce its opacity and reuse it.

what i tried in jsfiddle is

```
<li style="background-image: url('test.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
<font style="font-size:26px; color:#8c001a;">Title</font></li>
```

view jsfiddle at
    http://jsfiddle.net/m4wkq/1/

Comment: @Unykvis I didn't get your intension behind your comment...Is there any mistake in this suggestion ? as Above question is not self-explaining what user want

Comment: The other awnser is mine. Just found funny give a developer a photoshop solution. Sorry my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below html implementation and the used css code on that. That could be accomplished through CSS3.

**HTML Implementation:**

`<ul>
    <li class="test">
        <p>Dummy text!!!!!!</p>
    </li>
</ul>`

**Used CSS:**

`.test:before {
    background-image: url("20astro12.jpg");
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: -1;
}`

`.test {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 0;
}`

`p {
    color: #fff;
}`

Hope, this could help you to some extend! This CSS3 property doesn't support in Mozilla! So consider this feature for that browser at least. Please give it a quick try :) If it helps you a bit, then please vote :)

Cheers :)